# R aggregating certain rows

Tags: r

I have a two-column dataset with 5 minute frequency:

```
Dataset
          Time       Power
 2015-04-01 04:05:00        1
 2015-04-01 04:10:00        2
 2015-04-01 04:15:00        3
 2015-04-01 04:20:00        4
 2015-04-01 04:25:00        5
 2015-04-01 04:30:00        6
  ......
```

How can I aggregate it into a 15 minute frequency dataset? The new dataset should use every third timestamp as the new timestamp and the new power should be the sum of every three power value.

```
New dataset
          Time       Power
 2015-04-01 04:15:00        1+2+3
 2015-04-01 04:30:00        4+5+6
  ......
```

Comment: Hi Guys,  One more question regarding this problem. What if the time interval of the raw data is not fixed? For example, the time interval may be 1 min, or 2 min, or 10 min? Is there an efficient way to handle this to manipulate the data so it has 15 mins time interval? (usually the time stamp will be at 0, 15, 30, and 45.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
data.frame(T=df$Time[c(F,F,T)], P=rowSums(matrix(df$Power,,3,T)))
#                    T     P
#1 2015-04-01 04:15:00     6
#2 2015-04-01 04:30:00    15
```

We create a data frame with the 15-minute interval by recycling two false indices with a true value. Finally, the sum of rows is taken of the Power column layered into rows of three.

**Benchmark**

```
microbenchmark(
plafort = data.frame(T=big.df$Time[c(F,F,T)], P=rowSums(matrix(big.df$Power,,3,T))),
josilber = data.frame(Time=big.df$Time[seq(3, nrow(big.df), by=3)],
             Power=tapply(big.df$Power, floor((seq(nrow(big.df))-1)/3), sum))
)
#Unit: milliseconds
#expr        min         lq       mean    median         uq        max neval
#plafort   1.250796   1.345753   1.451546   1.46044   1.527486   2.045416   100
#josilber 176.438850 180.862507 187.434138 186.37592 189.628021 340.325792   100
```

**Data**

```
big.df <- data.frame(Time = rep(df$Time, 1e4), Power = rep(df$Power, 1e4))
```

Comment: Thanks! It works as magic. Much better than the for loop I wrote. In addition, the raw data may not have 3n rows, so I add script to remove additional rows.

Comment: You can remove additional rows by doing this first: `lastrow <- tail(which(1:nrow(df) %% 3 == 0), 1)` to get the last measurable row. Then subset the data frame by it `df <- df[1:lastrow, ]`. Then run the same script in the answer.

Comment: Hi, plafort. One more question regarding this problem. What if the time interval of the raw data is not fixed? For example, the time interval may be  1 min, or 2 min, or 10 min? Is there an efficient way to handle this to manipulate the data so it has 15 mins time interval? (usually the time stamp will be at 0, 15, 30, and 45.

Answer (score 1):

Create a column identifying the window for each observation (using vector recycling):

```
> df$window <- df$Time + minutes(5*c(2,1,0))
> print(df)
                 Time power              window
1 2015-04-01 00:05:00     1 2015-04-01 00:15:00
2 2015-04-01 00:10:00     2 2015-04-01 00:15:00
3 2015-04-01 00:15:00     3 2015-04-01 00:15:00
4 2015-04-01 00:20:00     4 2015-04-01 00:30:00
5 2015-04-01 00:25:00     5 2015-04-01 00:30:00
6 2015-04-01 00:30:00     6 2015-04-01 00:30:00
```

Then group by window, and sum:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% group_by(window) %>% summarize(power=sum(power)) -> newdf
> print(newdf)
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

               window power
1 2015-04-01 00:15:00     6
2 2015-04-01 00:30:00    15
```

Comment: Can you post the `dput` for your `df` data frame? I am not getting the output that you are showing.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.frame(Time=dat$Time[seq(3, nrow(dat), by=3)],
           Power=tapply(dat$Power, floor((seq(nrow(dat))-1)/3), sum))
#                  Time Power
# 0 2015-04-01 04:15:00     6
# 1 2015-04-01 04:30:00    15
```